# Derivative of orthogonal null space projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P=I-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ be orthogonal null space projection of $A$. My goal is to find a simple expression for $\dot{P}$. Simple in the sense that it becomes easy to write it down as software code. I can compute $A$,$\dot{A}$ and would thus like to see a very compact expression in terms of $A$ and $\dot{q}$ only. What I have so far is the following
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}P=&\frac{d}{dt}\left[I-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A\right]\\
=&-\left[\frac{d}{dt}A^T\right](AA^T)^{-1}A-A^T\frac{d}{dt}\left[(AA^T)^{-1}A\right]\\
=&-\dot{A}^T(AA^T)^{-1}A-A^T\left[\frac{d}{dt}(AA^T)^{-1}\right]A-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\dot{A}.
\end{align*}
Note that for $K$ invertible we have that
\begin{gather*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left[KK^{-1}\right]=\frac{d}{dt}I=0\implies\left[\frac{d}{dt}K\right]K^{-1}+K\frac{d}{dt}K^{-1}=0\\
\implies \frac{d}{dt}K^{-1}=-K^{-1}\dot{K}K^{-1}.
\end{gather*}
It then follows that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}P=&-\dot{A}^T(AA^T)^{-1}A-A^T\left[-(AA^T)^{-1}\left[\frac{d}{dt}AA^T\right](AA^T)^{-1}\right]A-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\dot{A} \\
=&-\dot{A}^T(AA^T)^{-1}A+A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\left[\dot{A}A^T+A\dot{A}^T\right](AA^T)^{-1}A-A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\dot{A}\\
=&-\dot{A}^T(AA^T)^{-1}A+A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\left[\left[\dot{A}A^T+A\dot{A}^T\right](AA^T)^{-1}A-\dot{A}\right].
\end{align*}

Edit: A is a function of $t$. In particular it holds that
$$A=\frac{d\Phi}{dq}(q(t)),$$
where $q\in\mathbb{R}^{n_q}$.

Comment: $A$ is a function of $t$???

Comment: @copper.hat yes, A is a function of $t$.